# How map osm way in graphhopper?

Tags: graphhopper

I need to store an edgeId-osmWayId Map during import from OSM file, to use it during routing.
Is it possible? 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could store this information to a map while import. As it grows really big I suggest using a preallocated long-array with as many entries as there are edges. E.g. use a custom encoder:

```
CarFlagEncoder carEncoder = new CarFlagEncoder(5, 5, 3) {
   @Override
   public void applyWayTags(OSMWay way, EdgeIteratorState edge) {
      ghEdgeIdToOSMWayIdMap[edge.getEdge()] = way.getId();
      super.applyWayTags(way, edge);
   }
};
setEncodingManager(new EncodingManager(carEncoder, ...));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. <br/> I create my map in this way :<br/> [code] protected void storeOsmWayID( int edgeId, long osmWayId )
     {
         if (getOsmWayIdSet().contains(osmWayId))
         {
             getEdgeIdToOsmWayIdMap().put(edgeId, osmWayId);
         }
         // Creo associazione tra edgeId e osmWayId
         osmEdgeIdOsmWayIdMap.put(edgeId, osmWayId);
     }[code] <br/> but i have no idea how to store it in my graph and use it during routing. E.g. in a custom Weighting.

Comment: Have a look into the weighting documentation describing something similar (weighting.md)

Comment: I would like to create my custom Weighting in this way:   Weighting customWeighting = new MyFastestWeighting(ghEdgeIdToOSMWayIdMap, encoder);  But how get ghEdgeIdToOSMWayIdMap created during import?  Should i save it like StorableProperties properties?

Comment: You can use whatever storage component you like or just GraphHoppers DataAccess implementations

Comment: maybe I should have a look into com.graphhopper.storage.GraphExtension interface?